# How to get a request object in Freemarker

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, freemarker

In Velocity template engine I could just use a model variable

```
$request
```

which is a instance of HttpServletRequest. How to get a http request object in Freemarker template engine? According to the freemarker documentation,

http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/ext/servlet/HttpRequestHashModel.html#getRequest--

there is a class HttpRequestHashModel and its method returns a instance of HttpServletRequest.

So the question is, how to access this object in spring boot? I found some information about using a

```
${Request}
```

variable, but I got an error that it returns a null/missing object.

Comment: The `Request` variable exists if you are using FreeMarker through the `FreemarkerServlet`, which Spring MVC doesn't do. Otherwise FreeMarker itself doesn't define such variable; exposing such thing is up to Spring MVC in this case. Same with Velocity. Have you tried `${request}` (with lower case) in FreeMarker?

Comment: The `request` variable doesn't exist, but I checked for `Request` variable and it is sent to my model. Somehow freemarker detects it, but I doesn't know how to interact with it and what type of class it is.

Comment: What kind of information do you want to get from the request? Perhaps there is another way.

Comment: @Jeroen I would like to have an access to `getPathInfo()` method of `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: I have checked the source code of `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView`, and the `Request` (and also `Session`, `Application`) variables expose the "attributes" (as the Servlet spec calls them) of the corresponding servlet scope. So you won't have `pathInfo` and such there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Spring does not expose the request directly to the template, however by default it does expose the model attribute **springMacroRequestContext**, which contains a lot of information about the request.

The **springMacroRequestContext** variable allows you to fetch information about the request.

For instance:

```
<html lang="${springMacroRequestContext.locale.language}" class="no-js">
```

or

```
${springMacroRequestContext.contextPath}
```

With your requirement of getting the path:

```
${springMacroRequestContext.requestUri}
```

should probably be sufficient.

See the **org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext** for all the available methods.

You can change the name of this attribute by setting the following property in your application.properties:

```
spring.freemarker.request-context-attribute=rc
```

This allows you to shorten the syntax in your template:

```
${rc.locale}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out.

Comment: If it solves your problem don't forget to mark the question as solved.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer. I find it very valuable, since I didn't find any information about this object on the spring documentation. They should point out this object in their documentation.